# Is there an easy way to expand this determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have this determinant and ask for an alternative way (not expanding way as we do always) to expand it:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
y^2+z^2 &xy& xz\\ xy&x^2+y^2&yz \\ xz&yz&x^2+z^2
\end{vmatrix}$$

If you think the only way is to manipulate the elements by doing many many elementary operations, please comment me. I am aware of that method.

Comment: Are you sure of your typing?? The whole thing is much prettier (call the matrix $A$) if you switch $A_{22}$ and $A_{33},$ and the answer much prettier

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, you are right, I think. Just the square then.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks.

Comment: I am suspicious of this matrix. If you exclude row $1$ and column $1,$  you see $$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} x^2+y^2 & yz \\ yz & x^2+z^2 \end{array} \right].$$ The variable that $x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+z^2$ have in common is $x,$ and that is the one that is excluded from the off-diagonal entry $yz.$ If you apply that to what happens if you exclude row $2$ and column $2,$ you would expect $xy$ to be the off-diagonal entry, but you have $yz.$ And similarly you'd expect $xz$ where you have $xy. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) and factoring we obtain for the above matrix $A$ the
determinant
$$
\det(A)=x^2(y^2+z^2)^2.
$$
This is without "many many elementary operation", but still by expanding, of course.

Edit: As Will has suggested, the above matrix should be just the square of the first matrix from the comments, and then the determinant is also the square.